# Replace one string within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
etst,tset,tets,ttest,teest,tesst,testt,4est,test,dest
```

I want to delete the value of an input box from the array, here's what I'm trying:

```
var el = document.getElementById('searchInput').value; // this is "test"

var toSearchFor = eld.slice(0,10); // the array above

for(var i=0; i < toSearchFor.length; i++) {
   toSearchFor[i] = toSearchFor[i].replace(/el/g, "");
}
```

It's simply not replacing "test" with ""

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.filter` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) to filter out the desired value:

```js
var arr = 'etst,tset,tets,ttest,teest,tesst,testt,4est,test,dest'.split(',')
   ,val = 'test'
   
document.querySelector('#result')
  .innerHTML = arr.filter(function (v) {return v != val});
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

A text field example in [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/jfooLr3q/)

Comment: This is great but if my array is as above 'toSearchFor' and I try toSearchFor.split(',') etc etc it fails saying toSearchFor.filter is not a function - example here http://jsfiddle.net/5uvbnpye/

Comment: Hi @DarrenSweeney, maybe the jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/jfooLr3q/ clarifies things?

Answer (score 1):

for global replacement of a string stored in a variable u need to create an instance of RegExp explicitly, like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(el, "g");
```

then use it in replace function:

```
toSearchFor[i] = toSearchFor[i].replace(regex, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in your regular expression: `/el/g`. This is trying to match the letters `el`, instead of whatever it's in the `el` variable. You could have done it using the [RegExp construtor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
// ...
regexp = new RegExp(el); // No need to use 'g' here since you're looking for the whole word
toSearchFor[i] = toSearchFor[i].replace(regexp, "");
// ...
```

Here's another way of doing it:

```
var eld = ['etst','tset','tets','ttest','teest','tesst','testt','4est','test','dest'];
// var el = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
var el = 'test';

console.log(eld);

var index = eld.indexOf(el);
if (index >= 0) {
    eld[index] = '';    
}

console.log(eld);
```

Here's the output:

```
["etst", "tset", "tets", "ttest", "teest", "tesst", "testt", "4est", "test", "dest"]
["etst", "tset", "tets", "ttest", "teest", "tesst", "testt", "4est", "", "dest"]
```

In this case, we're using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, so that we can access that element directly (if found).

I hope that helps!

Comment: If there are multiple instances of 'test' in the array this only strips out the first, is there a way to strip all out?

Comment: In that case, you would have to iterate through all of the elements of `eld`, as you were doing in the beginning.